# Mudar picture box clicando numa label

Tags: c#

Boa tarde,alguem poderia me ajudar? 
Gostaria de ao clicar sobre uma label minha picturebox mudasse.Estou fazendo um Quiz no windows form e tipo,as picturebox funcionam como o (wallpaper do botão) e a label (resposta/botão).Portanto a Label contem a resposta,se a pessoa ao clicar responder certo queria que a picturebox mudasse, a mesma coisa para resposta errada.Isso é o que tenho na parte das perguntas:

```
  switch (pergunt) //variavel para guardar as perguntas
        {
            case 1:

                Pergunta.Text = "Quem desenvolveu o C#?";
                resp1.Text = "Microsoft";//certa
                resp2.Text = "AMD";
                resp3.Text = "Sunbed Microsystems";
                resp4.Text = "Intel";

                if (resposta == 1) //essa variavel resposta não funciona,queria armazenar a resposta dada pelo utilizador ao clicar em uma das labels nela.
                {
                    pictureBox1.Load(@"..\RespostaCerta.png");

                }
                else 
                {
                    pictureBox2.Load(@"..\RespostaErrada.png");                  
                    pictureBox3.Load(@"..\RespostaErrada.png");
                    pictureBox4.Load(@"..\RespostaErrada.png");
                }


                break;
```

E o que tenho em cada uma das labels/botões é:

```
   private void resp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Limpa(); //Esse metodo serve para limpar as labels para assim ser possivel realizar o sorteamento das perguntas
        SortearP();// Sortea as perguntas
        resp1_Click = Convert.ToString(resposta); //Aqui que está o problema,não consigo converter o que está dentro da Label para um valor ex 1,para que eu consiga lá no switch das perguntas fazer o if para mudar a picture box

    }

  private void resp2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Limpa();
        SortearP();
        resp2_Click = Convert.ToString(resposta);
    }

    private void resp3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Limpa();
        SortearP();
        resp3_Click = Convert.ToString(resposta);
    }
 private void resp4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Limpa();
        SortearP();
        resp4_Click = Convert.ToString(resposta);
    }
```

E é isso,obrigada desde já ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma variável global da resposta que o usuário selecionou e guardar nela o valor do `Label` clicado. E sempre que chamar o `Limpa()`, o valor dessa variável é resetado. Após ter o valor da resposta, você pode chamar o método de verificar se essa variável está correta.

Após a declaração de classe, declare a variável `resposta`, considerando que `-1` é **sem resposta**.

```
protected int resposta = -1;
```

Então, sempre que um Label for clicado, manipule `resposta` para qual valor foi selecionado:

```
private void resp2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Limpa();
    SortearP();
    resposta = 2; // botão 2 pressionado, resposta 2
}
```

> **Nota importante:** retorne `resposta` para `-1` no método `Limpa()` para não fazer com que uma resposta esteja selecionada na próxima pergunta.

Após isso, chame o método de verificar se a resposta está correta. Adicione uma verificação para checar se foi definida uma resposta com `if(resposta == -1) return;`, assim saberás que o usuário não escolheu uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Você pode como alternativa mais simples usar o LabelLink que já possui evento de "click" (LinkClicked) para o comportamento que você deseja, da uma olhada na documentação com exemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked?view=netframework-4.8

Obrigado!